# I can't get all the messages from websocket

Tags: node.js, websocket

I'm trying to parse websocket from a third-party site. But I don't get all the messages. For example, in devtools I see that there are messages of two types `type: ka` and `type: data` https://prnt.sc/htrQRLy8p7T- , when I use the code below, I get only `type: ka` messages https://prnt.sc/KG8adKNKLJ8N.

Investigating devtools, I noticed that in the beginning several messages are sent to websocket, maybe because of this I am not getting all the messages, namely `type: data`, any ideas how I can get it? Maybe I should also send messages first somehow?

My code

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const ws = new WebSocket('wss://polkadot.polkastats.io/graphql', 'graphql-ws', {
    'origin': 'https://polkastats.io'
});

ws.on('open', () => console.log('open'));
ws.on('close', (err) => console.log('close', err));
ws.on('error', (err) => console.log('error', err));
ws.on('upgrade', () => console.log('upgrade'));
ws.on('ping', () => console.log('ping'));
ws.on('message', (messages) => {
    const chank = messages;
    console.log(JSON.parse(chank));
});
```